# In Java, can a process pipe stream reader encountering an IOException recover?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have some Java code, which starts other processes and reads their output using a `BufferedReader`, by calling `java.io.BufferedReader#readLine()` in a loop. Sometimes I see that `java.io.BufferedReader#readLine()` throws `IOException`, e.g. when the process quits unexpectedly (such things can happen in my case) etc.

The question is: what is the appropriate handling of an `BufferedReader#readLine()` throwing `IOException`: is there any case, when reading from the stream **again** could continue consuming the process output (assuming it was some kind of transient error), or does  `IOException` mean the stream is in failure and should be abandoned and closed?

I guess the whole issue boils down to one thing, if a a pipe stream encountering an I/O error can later recover from it and continue reading or not. My gut instinct tells me, it depends on the underlying operating system / JVM implementation, but I would love to hear inputs from people better versed in this topic than myself.

Comment: The cause could be anything, but in my experience an IOException renders the stream unusable

Comment: As a rule of thumb, absent documentation to the contrary, you have to assume that an object is left in an inconsistent state when one of its methods throws an exception.

Comment: If recovering from the erroneous state was actually possible it would have been a much better implementation to do exactly this instead of throwing an IOEexception. Throwing an exception when being able to recover would just pointlessly put the burden of errorhandling on the API user.